# Displaying X when Y is null and Z is null

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I would like to display certain dates if others come back as null...
What I've tried

```
case 
   when attv4.valueDateTime IS NOT NULL then attv4.valueDateTime
   when attv4.valueDateTime IS NULL then attv5.valueDateTime
   when (attv5.valueDateTime IS NULL AND attv4.valueDateTime IS NULL) then bpc.consentDate
   when (bpc.consentDate IS NULL AND attv4.valueDateTime IS NULL AND attv5.valueDateTime IS NULL) then col.collectDate 
end
```

I have also tried using multiple ISNULL's but when I do that, I get multiple records for the same person displaying the various dates that weren't null..

Comment: Have you tried using `coalesce`? `coalesce(attv4.valueDateTime, attv5.valueDateTime, bpc.consentDate, col.collectDate)`

Comment: In your current `CASE` you will never get past the first two conditions, because `attv4.valueDateTime` is either `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. You might get what you need when you switch the order (but only you know what's the correct result)

Comment: Since you are writing a CASE with cases that cannot be reached and "I have also tried using multiple ISNULL's but when I do that, I  get multiple records for the same person displaying the various dates that weren't null", it seems that in your desire to "display certain dates if others come back as null" you have not properly designed what "comes back" (per FROM & WHERE?) and what "gets displayed" (per later SELECT clause?). Please tell us what under what conditions a row appears in each base table & in your desired query output. (And example input & desired output would probably help.)

Answer (score 1):

I like `coalesce()` for this.  It captures exactly what you seem to want: the first non-null value in a priority-ordered list of values.

If you wanted to do it with a `CASE` expression, however, as you attempted to do, then that would look like this:

```
case 
  when attv4.valueDateTime IS NOT NULL then attv4.valueDateTime
  when attv5.valueDateTime IS NOT NULL then attv5.valueDateTime
  when bpc.consentDate     IS NOT NULL then bpc.consentDate
  else col.collectDate 
end
```

Note in particular that each successive `when` condition is considered only if all the previous ones evaluated to false; you do not need to reiterate the negatives of all those conditions in each successive predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the `isnull` calls like this:

```
isnull(attv4.valueDateTime, 
       isnull(attv5.valueDateTime, 
              isnull(bpc.consentDate, col.collectDate)))
```

Comment: COALESCE is known in more rdbms's than ISNULL.  ISNULL generally signifies that the user is using sql-server

Comment: Every DBMS which supports `CASE` **always** supports `COALESCE` & `NULLIF` which are just shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

sgeddes makes a good point that COALESCE() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx could be of good use here and you wont need your case statement at all.

```
COALESCE(attv4.valueDateTime, attv5.ValueDateTime, bpc.consentDate, col.collectdate)
```

In a case statement so the **first TRUE statement is returned**.  So you could write the statement like so which would automatically take into account 1 Value being null then the next etc.

```
CASE
   WHEN attv4.ValueDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN attv4.ValueDateTime
   WHEN attv5.ValueDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN attv4.ValueDateTime
   WHEN bpc.ConsentDate IS NOT NULL THEN bpc.ConsentDate
   ELSE col.collectDate
END
```

As @dnoeth pointed out and I think we all read past too quick was that your first 2 conditions will always be satisfied so becuase attv4.ValueDateTime is either NULL or NOT NULL.  If NOT NULL the value you get would be attv4.ValueDateTime and if NULL you would get attv5.valueDateTime, but you would never get bpc.consentDate or col.collectDate.....

However if you are getting **multiple records per person it is probably more due to the JOINS rather than the case statement**.  You  could look at calling DISTINCT and eliminating columns not used, or use a ROW_NUMBER() and select the results where = 1.